# Unable rename the first element of OOTB SharePoint bread crumbs

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, breadcrumb, customization

I have a requirement where I need to rename the first element of the bread crumbs to another name. Currently it displays the name of the site i.e `XYZ Intranet` but instead of that I want to rename this as `HOME`.

Is there any way other than using a custom JavaScript to achieve this functionality. I have researched on this but have come across a single solution of using the custom JavaScript for this purpose.

Please suggest solutions for this.

The following is the code block that I have added in the master page for rendering the breadcrumbs.

```
<asp:SiteMapPath runat="server" SiteMapProviders="SPContentMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false" NodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbNode default-fontcolorC" CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbCurrentNode default-fontcolorC" RootNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbRootNode default-fontcolorC" HideInteriorRootNodes="false" SkipLinkText=""/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I have done it in one of my implementations:

```
   <!--Breadcrumb start -->

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBreadcrumb" runat="server">
    <div id="breadcrumb">
        <asp:SiteMapPath    
            ID="contentNavigation"
            runat="server"  
            SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider"
            RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false"
            NodeStyle-CssClass="NodeBreadcrumb"
            CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbCurrentNode"
            RootNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbRootNode"
            HideInteriorRootNodes="false"
            SkipLinkText="">
            <RootNodeTemplate></RootNodeTemplate>
        </asp:SiteMapPath>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            var rootNode = $("span[id$=contentNavigation] > span:eq(0)");
            if (rootNode.attr("class") == "breadcrumbRootNode") {   

                $(rootNode).next("span a").text.replace('MyIntranet', 'Home');; }
        });
    </script>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<!-- Breadcrumb end -->
```